# How to properly watch for gmail push notifications

Tags: python, push-notification, google-api, gmail-api

I don't understand how to properly watch for gmail push notifications (also i know nothing about the web in terms of coding).

Google give this tutorial page: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

What i did so far:

- Prerequisites : DONE
- Create a topic : DONE
- Create a subscription : DONE
- Grant publish rights on your topic : DONE
- watch() method works and gives this result: `{'historyId': '714707', 'expiration': '1618824687477'}`

So far everything works fine, but my knowledge stops here. It seems to me that i have to implement some kind of infinite while loop on the watch method, to check for `historyId` changes. But if so, why would there be a `stop()` method on the `watch()` method, and also why would there be a `expiration` field on the watch result ?
What should i do from there ?

Here is my implementation so far:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials


SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']
MY_TOPIC_NAME = 'my/toppic/name'

creds = None
if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
                creds.refresh(Request())
else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('./my_creds.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())



gmail = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
request = {'labelIds': ['INBOX'],'topicName': MY_TOPIC_NAME}
gmail.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute()
```

Answer (score 2):

### I think there is some misunderstanding about the concept of push notifications

- Once you set-up a watch request, push notifications will be automatically received by your application when there is a **mailbox update**
- A **mailbox update** takes place for example when you receive a new email
- The `historyId` in simple words reflects the status of your mailbox at a certain moment (e.g. when you set-up a watch request)
- This value is only important for reference, because unless [specified otherwise](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sync) you will only get notifications about mailbox updates taking place after the moment corresponding to the specific `historyId`
- You do not need an endless loop for receiving notifications, you only need to [renew the watch request every 7 days](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#renewing_mailbox_watch).
- Depending on your implementation you will probably need some HTTP library that handles POST requests - whenever the Gmail API posts notifications to your server.

Comment: Thanks, i'll dig into this when i have the time and i'll post my entire solution here